# showing macOS 11 or later required ! zsh: abort as a run a simple code with module Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio, tkinter

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
# Creating a Label Widget
mylabel = Label(root,text="Hello world!")
# Showing in onto the screen
mylabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

as I do pip install tkinter in my mac terminals
it gives this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

Comment: `tkinter` is part of python's standard library, just run the code directly.

Comment: but how 
I tried every possible this I can do